# Selecting from a list of 200-character items

Tags: information-architecture

#### Background

I'm a product manager working on an application that allows users to send out custom email campaigns (e.g. newsletters, coupons, etc).

On our campaign edit page where the user prepares their mail before sending, we allow the user to select from a predefined list of subjects and body templates. These predefined lists are necessary for our customers to be able to quickly select and send out their campaigns.

[image: Campaign Edit page]

#### The Problem

The mail body templates can be up to 200 characters, so a standard select box won't suffice.

**How can we allow the user to select from a list of 200-character templates?**

Comment: Your question isn't very clear but I think you're asking for an alternative to the select box that will handle long text strings for easy selection of email subjects and content. Is that correct?

Comment: Absolutely , Yes  @AndrewMartin

Comment: I've edited your question to try to clarify what you're asking, I hope you don't mind! Please feel free to [edit] your question again if I made any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

You can let user define defaults for a new campaign. Build a configuration page for setting those defaults, and fill the create form with them. This is what Mailchimp does for using predefined content for a new campaign.